# Can someone help me create SUMIFS function equivalent on Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I basically picked up Python last week, and although I am currently learning the basics, I've been tasked with building a small program in python at work. And would appreciate some help on this.
I would like to create a SUMIFS function similar to the excel version. My data contains a cash flow date (CFDATE), portfolio name (PORTFOLIO) and cash flow amount (CF). I want tot sum the CF based on which portfolio it belongs to and based on the date on which it falls. 
I have managed to achieve this using the code below, however I am struggling to output my results as an array/table where the header row comprises of all the portfolios, and the initial column is a list of the dates (duplicates removed) and the CF are grouped according to each combination of (CFDATE,PORTFOLIO).

e.g of desired output:
         PORTFOLIO->     'A'   'B'   'C'
CFDATE

'30/09/2017'            300   600  300
'31/10/2017'            300     0  600

code used so far:

```
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
from numpy import matrix
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = DataFrame(pd.read_csv("...\Test.csv"))
portfolioMapping = sorted(list(set(df.PORTFOLIO)))
cfDateMapping = list(set(df.CFDATE))


for i in range(0,len(portfolioMapping)):
    dfVar = df.CF * np.where(df.PORTFOLIO == portfolioMapping[i] , 1, 0)
    for j in range(0,len(cfDateMapping)):
        dfVar1 = df.CF/df.CF * np.where(df.CFDATE == cfDateMapping[j] , 1, 0)
        print([portfolioMapping[i],[cfDateMapping[j]],sum(dfVar*dfVar1)])
```

The data is basically in this form:

```
PORTFOLIO   CFDATE  CF
A   30/09/2017  300
A   31/10/2017  300
C   31/10/2017  300
B   30/09/2017  300
B   30/09/2017  300
C   30/09/2017  300
C   31/10/2017  300
C   31/10/2017  300
```

I would really appreciate some help on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `sum` + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['CFDATE', 'PORTFOLIO'])['CF'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
PORTFOLIO     A    B    C
CFDATE                   
30/09/2017  300  600  300
31/10/2017  300    0  900
```

Or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='CFDATE', 
                    columns='PORTFOLIO', 
                    values='CF', 
                    aggfunc=sum, 
                    fill_value=0)
print (df)
PORTFOLIO     A    B    C
CFDATE                   
30/09/2017  300  600  300
31/10/2017  300    0  900
```

Comment: Thanks a great deal for your help both methods worked perfectly, but I've gone with the pivot_table method.

Comment: It is up to you, but first solution is faster in larger df.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with Pandas's [`pivot_table()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df.pivot_table(index='CFDATE', columns=['PORTFOLIO'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
```

The result is the following:

```
PORTFOLIO   A   B   C
CFDATE          
30/09/2017  300 600 300
31/10/2017  300 0   900
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys, this site is gonna make my learning experience so much more enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best in your case would be to use a `groupby` method like the following:

```
df.groupby(['PORTFOLIO', 'CFDATE']).sum()

                      CF
PORTFOLIO CFDATE         
A         30/09/2017  600
          31/10/2017  300
B         30/09/2017  600
C         30/09/2017  300
          31/10/2017  900
```

Basically, once you have grouped your `dataframe` `df`, you can then perform various method on it (like `sum()`, `mean()`, `min()`, `max()`, etc)

Also, you cans store you grouped dataframe in an object like the following:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['PORTFOLIO', 'CFDATE'])
```

It makes it more flexible to perform different calculations afterward:

```
grouped.sum()
grouped.mean()
grouped.count()
```